# Getting fragment instance in my activity

Tags: android, fragment

Is there some way I get already created currently displayed same instance of fragment in my activity. I **DON'T** to use

- `findFragmentById(int id)`, simply I never created that
- `findFragmentByTag(String tag)`, because  I am not adding tag in every fragment .offcourse due to some requirement.
- `getFragment(Bundle bundle, String key)`, because I never am putting in bundle.

Although I may look like fool to mention that, but I want something like this. Is activity keep some fragment instance somewhere.??

What can be the best approach I can take to achieve this requirement.

**UPDATE**

Okay, so let me tell you why I can't use above methods. If I am adding various fragment in one activity, where I always want to come back to one fragment when back is clicked. (As we have in navigation drawer, u know). And unless there are inner fragment. so for that I don't want to add in the back stack.

Now even if I have the tag associated with my fragments, I cant say for 8 fragment if- else-if-else for getting the tag. That I know is not correct. So first two ways goes out of my option. Now third one. I exactly don't know where to keep it. And even if I keep it where will I  get the bundle and key every time I just want my fragment.

Comment: which api level/support package version?

Comment: the FragmentManager is the one that holds all the references of the fragments. Additional, you might tell us how you create your fragments instead, maybe that opens up another solution.

Comment: api level11 currently but cn chnge to 14

Comment: @bofredo I understand that. but cn u point me out the method apart from above ones

Comment: no, i don't know any other option there and i don't really know why i should, because they cover all there is needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can get from fragment Manager

```
List<Fragment>  fragList=fManager.getFragments();
    for(Fragment fr: fragList){
        String fragClassName = fr.getClass().getName();
        if(fragClassName.equals(Abc.class.getName())){
            Log.i("Fragment:","Abc");
        }else if (fragClassName.equals(Xyz.class.getName())) {
            Log.i("Fragment:","Xyz");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ohh. Still checking for 8-9 fragment this if-else loop. Do you really think that's the decent way/ And what if I need to get my current fragment often. every time putting my thread to loop for this. I am not sure, may be that's the only way. But still I am looking for better approach where I don't have to loop in my each fragments.

Comment: And BTW why I am not getting `fragmentManger.getFragments()` in my fragment manger class. I am using android.app.FragmentManager not V4

Comment: Yes you can get. You understand your problem better than me

Comment: I didn't understand your latest comment, how is that useful!!!. And what is that I can get??